# Gravitational wave thought experiment: changing circumference?

Tags: general-relativity, gravitational-waves, thought-experiment

I just started learning about gravitational waves and how they can cause the distance between 2 neighbouring particles to increase and decrease in an oscillatory manner. I made up a thought experiment though to try and wrap my head around the idea.

Imagine a ring (with radius $R$) of test masses surrounding some generator of gravitational waves at their centre. Here's a diagram:
[image: diagram]
Now, imagine the generator produces a short burst of gravitational waves radially outward which passes through the test masses. Assuming the polarisation is right, the distance between neighbouring masses will oscillate. However, this happens with *all pairs of neighbouring particles at the same time*, so the circumference of the ring must oscillate too. Yet, if the wave burst is short then the radius of the ring is approximately unchanged.

How can this be? I'm comfortable with this discrepancy between radius and circumference as it arises in, say, Schwarzschild spacetime, but in that case it makes sense to me from the geometry (e.g. by visualising Flamm's paraboloid). I don't see how a gravitational wave produces an analogous disturbance in the geometry which can explain this discrepancy.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if the "short burst" is necessary, but I include it to ensure that most of space between the generator and the test masses is unperturbed when the wave reaches the masses.

Comment: As far as I know this kind of thought experiment is about the "freely falling test particles (masses)". So the radius would never remain unchanged.

Comment: Do gravitational waves *increase* distances? I thought they only shorten.

Comment: How can this be? Well the test masses can only move in one direction at a time and in a tangential way. Why would the circumference change?

Comment: Again, what's your definition of "test mass"? The picture you see in almost every book on GWs is not exact in the sense that the masses do move because they are freely falling. Otherwise, we know from General Relativity that they would feel force and the gravitational waves could not affect them as we might think.